# ffmpeg compile for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg, cross-compiling

Was trying to compile ffmpeg using vs2012 , its saying unsupported ms version used 2013 or above .

also tried compiling with mingw , got the shared libraries , but unable to link with vs 2012 project giving unresolved symbols error .

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_get_class referenced in function _wmain
: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_find_encoder_by_name referenced in function _wmain

not sure how to proceed . could nay help on this pls .

tried the way specified in the link https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC but could not make it .